# How to build a loading balancing for routing service in wcf 4.0?

Tags: wcf, routes, load-balancing

1. I'm a fan of WCF from China. Now, a problem occured as below pic. Who can teach me which point should I focuse.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMRrm.png)

Comment: Thank you for your advice in advance

Comment: Please add proper description to question.